# Asp.Net RadioButtonList Issue When Duplicate Value Present In Source

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am trying to bind data in RadioButtonList, but `SelectedValue` and
`SelectedItem` showing wrong result when there is any duplicate record
present in the Binding source.

This is How I am trying to bind the RadioButtonList:

```
List<object> _source = new List<object>(){
    new{Id=1,Client_Name="ABC",DBConfigName="ABC"},
    new{Id=1,Client_Name="ABC1",DBConfigName="ABC"},
    new{Id=1,Client_Name="ABC2",DBConfigName="ABC"},
};

rdMappedClientList.DataSource = _source;
rdMappedClientList.DataTextField = "Client_Name";
rdMappedClientList.DataValueField = "DBConfigName";
rdMappedClientList.DataBind();
```

As you can see the DataSource `_source` holding duplicate record for `DBConfigName`.
In this case if I tried to execute `_SelectedIndexChanged` event then it'll return wrong result.

There is no documentation for `RadioButtonList` class that It's `DataValueField` should not contains duplicate value.

If I changed the `DataValueField` for this to `Id` it'll work perfectly.

**Note:** There is no:

- Compile time or run time error
- Documentation mentioning for Unique values for `DataValueField`

So, I am not able to understand this.

Comment: The change is detected based on the data field value. So if they are all the same then there is no change. But that has nothing to do with allowing duplicates.

Comment: The core issue seems to be the duplicate data (it can even be labeled "incorrect data"). Admittedly I do not understand your domain logic, but it seems the correct approach would be to deal with the incorrect data, rather than attempt to re-engineer how the RadioButtonList works.

Comment: what *wrong result* is?

Comment: any reference documentation? please provide. @VDWWD

Comment: I don't have it. And why should it matter? What else is there to trigger change detection apart from the Key value of a ListItem.